# What is the correct folder structure for dynamic nested routes in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, directory, next.js

I've been going over the Next.js docs and think I understand the [slug].js dynamic routing process, but I struggling to understand nested dynamic routes in terms of folder structure.

If I want to make a user based application, how would I achieve `/user/[userid]/post/[postId]`?

And a would like something like this:

```
 user
 - [id].js // e.g. user/1
 - [userId]
 - - post
 - - - [postId].js // e.g. user/[userId]/post/[postId]
```

But this throws an error about [slugs] as I think you can't have two slugs in the same folder.

Can anyone explain the correct folder structure to achieve this? Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of `[id].js` create an file named `index.js` in `[userId]` folder which will be used to render the page for route path `/user/[userId]/`.

```js
pages/
 user/
  [userId]/
    - index.js        // will match for /user/1234
    post/
      - index.js      // will match for /user/1234/post
      - [postId].js   // will match for /user/1234/post/some-post
```

Similarly creating an `index.js` under folder `post` will be useful to match for route path `/user/[userId]/post/` which can be used show a list for post for that user.

An [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing) with a folder structure for a similar use case.